# Unable to replace or define a named ui:insert block

Tags: jsf

I just learned that I can create a main template which I can replace with different other `xhtml` `jsf` pages using `ui:insert`, `ui:define` and `ui:include src`So I did some research online and tried to display the combined pages.

However, I can't get to define the named `ui:insert` **content** block with another content *(I want to put what register.xhtml page has when user goes to the register page)*

**template.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/font-awesome.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/mywebsite.css"/>
        <h:outputScript name="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"/>
        <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.js"/>
    </h:head>    

    <h:body>

        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <!--content container-->
                <ui:insert name="content">
                    <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <!--footer container-->
                <ui:insert name="footer">
                    <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

**header.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h1>Default Header</h1>
</ui:composition>
```

**content.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    >
    <h1>Default Content</h1>
</ui:composition>
```

**footer.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h1>Default Footer</h1>
</ui:composition>
```

**register.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h1>I AM REGISTER</h1>
</ui:composition>
```

What I would like to be able to do is to replace the **content** block with  `register.xhtml` when user goes to `localhost:8080/mywebsite/register.xhtml`

I want to replace the `default content` `div`. Only when user goes to the **register** page (`localhost:8080/mywebsite/register.xhtml`) but keep the **header** and **footer**.

[image]

I hope you can help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your register.xhtml should be like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
    <h1>I AM REGISTER</h1>
</ui:define></ui:composition>
```

You must add `template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"` in the `ui:composition` tag and override the actual content as

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h1>I AM REGISTER</h1>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually did that but didn't work the first time. I found out that the browser mistakenly interpreted it to be xml. I found that I had to change the mapping url-patter from *.* to *.xhtml
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>